# WebView shows blank page when running behind proxy

Tags: java, javafx-8, javafx-webengine

As simple as possible:

```
public class WebViewSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // I tried without this proxy configuration, same result.
        System.getProperties().put("proxySet", "true");
        System.getProperties().put("proxyHost", "http://127.0.0.1");
        System.getProperties().put("proxyPort", 5677);
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        final WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load("http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(webView));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I'm using `cntlm` to handle the proxy authentication. (I'm running `jdk8u5`).

What's wrong ?

Comment: You may want to change `System.getProperties().put` by `System.setProperty`, it's what didn't work with me.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring `https` solves the problem.

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "5677");
```